# about EncodedImage in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

Suppose i have an animated GIF image name **test.GIF** added to my project in BlackBerry JDE to be used in AnimatedGIFField class. and now i need to convert it to Encoded image.
 In the reference it is given to create encoded image the following function

public static EncodedImage createEncodedImage(byte[] data,
                                              int offset,
                                              int length)

Plz give me the code to convert test.GIF to encoded image????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code

```
EncodedImage encImg = GIFEncodedImage.getEncodedImageResource("test.gif");
```

if you need `GIFEncodedImage` then cast `encImg` to `GIFEncodedImage`.

```
GIFEncodedImage img = (GIFEncodedImage) encImg;
```

Answer (score 0):

By the way, casting **EncodedImage** to **GIFEncodedImage** fails on OS7. You have to rename your gif extension to **.agif** to make it work.